# Why can't I access an EC2 instance, located in a public subnet even though it has a public IPv4 address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes

I am doing my first steps in Amazon EC2 and therefore i created an EC2 instance in a public subnet (i actually work on getting the essentiell background knowledge).

I am able to access the instance via RDP, but **i am not able to access the instance via it´s public IPv4 address** (connection termination due to timeout).

If i ping the IPv4 address i got the message:
4 packages sent
0 packages received
4 packages lost
100% loss

Maybe there is any obvious reason (misconfiguration in security group?)

**VPC configuration:**

[image]

**Instance - configuration, including security-group:**

[image]

**Some detailed information:**

- The instance was placed in a public subnet.
- The option "assign public ipv4 address automatically" was set to
  "enabled" inside the subnet. This options was also chosen for the instance prior to first start
- The instance has a public IPv4 address and a public IPv4-DNS (so EIP shouldn´t be necessary?)
- The routing table of the public subnet has a route to internet gateway
- network ACL is fully opened in both directions
- ports 80, 443, 8443 are open for target 0.0.0.0/0, ports 22 & 3389 only for own IPv4 (incoming data)
- outgoing data traffic is also completely open (target 0.0.0.0/0)

**Are my security groups configured too restrictively /wrong? Maybe a firewall issue?**
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure about your own ip adresses. You need your public ip to be whitelisted. Check your public ip here https://ifconfig.me. Also you haven't opened icmp port so ping will fail. Whitelist icmp protocol and check again with ping.

Comment: Are you able to telnet your machine from local (Laptop)? telnet public_ip 22 ? What's the output you are getting while performing telnet.

Comment: I whitelisted ICMP protocol now for 0.0.0.0/0 but i still got no valid ping response (still all packages lost + timeout). Maybe it´s some kind of firewall problem?

Comment: Does your NACL allow traffic as well (you can find it in the VPC Service)?

Comment: The network ACLs of all subnets also allow data traffic in both directions by rule "allow" with target 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Change security group if it's the default one(no sense but I have seen a couple of cases here where it has worked). Secondly check your route table, it must be it. You can log into the node via ssm and try pinging google to see if outbound traffic is allowed. If not, then surely it's your routing which has some issues. It's not guaranteed that if outbound traffic is allowed, there is no issue becauuse you might have NAT.

Comment: I am confused. You say that "I am able to access the instance via RDP", but then you say "i am not able to access the instance via its public IPv4 address". Then how did you access it via RDP -- did you not use its IP address? And when you say "access", how are you trying to access it -- RDP, SSH, HTTP, TELNET, etc?

Comment: My first idea was, that as soon as i´ve created a running EC2 instance with a public IPv4 address, i should be able to access it with my browser with https://<public instance IPv4>. But i suppose there are good reasons (security issues), why that isn´t possible in this way (I think I understood this a little too simplified at first).